# Recommended way to install Ansible modules from PyPI

Tags: python, ansible, pypi

When creating new projects in Python, the recommended way to install dependencies from PyPI is to use `virtualenv` or `venv`, instead of installing the modules globally.

I want to install the [github_release module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/github_release_module.html), but it depends on `github3.py`, which is not available in the Ubuntu repositories.

What is the recommended way to install Python modules for Ansible in the host? Should I just install them globally? I currently use Ansible from their official Ubuntu PPA.

Comment: How did you install ansible? apt-get? Why don't you use virtualenv?

Comment: I have just added that to the question!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use wheel to install.
You can do both ways:

- Download wheel file from PyPI
- Compile your own wheel

Here is the command example for compile wheel:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=~/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

Here is the command example to install wheel files:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=~/wheels -r requirement.txt
pip install --no-index --find-links=~/wheels uwsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `--user` install option, the package will be installed in your home directory(`~/.local`) instead of the global environment.

you can try as below.

```
$ pip install --user github3
$ ls -la ~/.local/lib/python/site-packages/ | grep github3
drwxrwxr-x  44 tell_k  staff  1496  3 23 08:32 github3
drwxrwxr-x   9 tell_k  staff   306  3 23 08:32 github3.py-0.9.6.dist-info
```

see also full documentation.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-user
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs